# angular js ng-option not working for select tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular2-directives

I'm trying to get the ng-option to use a JSON formatted array, but not sure why it's not displaying the select option rows. For instance:

index.js:

```
$scope.seloptions= [{ key: k1, name: n1 },{ key: k2, name: n2 }];
```

index.html:

```
<select name="set_aside" ng-model="set_aside" ng-options="option.key for option in seloptions track by name"></select>
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.  The select tag is not getting populated.

**EDIT** 
Also assume that the necessary setup for the angular code is there and both files are in same directory.

Comment: first of all your values k1 , n1, k2, n2 should be defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are tracking by name which is undefined.
update line :

```
ng-options="option.key for option in seloptions track by name"
```

to

```
ng-options="option.key for option in seloptions track by option.name"
```

**Working example** :

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.seloptions= [{ key: "key1", name: "n1" },{ key:" key2", name: "n2" }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select name="set_aside" ng-model="set_aside" ng-options="option.key for option in seloptions track by option.name">
        <option value="">Select One</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I know i've seen other examples where it was ok to reference name without option.  Ok thanks.